# Guzzle CacheSubscriber first response is empty

Tags: php, guzzle

When I execute a normal Guzzle request with CacheSubscriber attached, it gets executed, data gets stored in the cache (storage doesn't matter, tried array and Redis), but then the request body is empty. Both Guzzle and CacheSubscriber seem to work properly. Just the first request has an empty body.

Next request shows the results from cache.

Guzzle Version - 5.2.0

Guzzle CacheSubscriber - dev-master

Is there anything I'm missing? Does anyone have the CacheSubscriber running?

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure what's the cause, maybe I understand the intention of getContents wrong, but using

```
$content = (string)$response->getBody(); // Works
```

instead of

```
$content = $response->getBody()->getContents(); // Won't work
```

solved the problem for me.

Comment: This really is a weird behaviour, guzzle needs better documentation. I've lost a few hours trying to debug it